# subsetting dataframe based on related_id column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe called `df` that has an `id` column and a `related_id` column. If the related_id is not null that means there is a desktop version and a mobile version.
I want to subset this dataset to keep only desktop instances if there is a related id.

input:

```
id related_id type
1  2          desktop
2  1          mobile
3  NaN        desktop
4  6          desktop
5  NaN        mobile
6  4          mobile
```

output:

```
id related_id type
1  2          desktop
3  NaN        desktop
4  6          desktop
5  NaN        mobile
```

how can i do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Try with boolean masking:

```
mask=(df['related_id'].isna()) | (df['type']=='desktop')
```

Finally:

```
result=df[mask]
```

Now if you print result you will get your desired output:

```
    id  related_id  type
0   1   2.0         desktop
2   3   NaN         desktop
3   4   6.0         desktop
4   5   NaN         mobile
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `numpy` `sort`

```
df[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['id','related_id']].values,axis=1)).duplicated().values]
   id  related_id     type
0   1         2.0  desktop
2   3         NaN  desktop
3   4         6.0  desktop
4   5         NaN   mobile
```

Answer (score 1):

We can place the necessary conditions in query method to filter the df.

```
df.query('related_id.isna() | type=="desktop"')
```

**Output**

```
    id  related_id  type
0   1   2.0       desktop
2   3   NaN       desktop
3   4   6.0       desktop
4   5   NaN       mobile
```